# Asp net boilerplate - date format dd/mm/yy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date-format, globalization, aspnetboilerplate

In using Asp net boilerplate framework (abp 1.5.1) in my project.  I want to use date format `dd/mm/yyyy` in my project. For this I've tried in web.config

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

In the global.asax.cs I've added following code

```
protected override void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.Application_BeginRequest(sender, e);
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;
}
```

Comment: You do not need the code in `Application_BeginRequest` is you have set the culture in the `web.config` file.

Comment: Also I've tried that way. But not working.

Comment: I don't use boilerplate framework, but just commenting the the code in `Application_BeginRequest` is pointless - the culture is already `en-GB` because you set it in the web.config file.

Comment: Dates have no format. *Strings* do. Formats apply **only** when you convert a DateTime value into a string either explicitly or implicitly. Where did you see this string? On a web page? A query result? Database field? Post the relevant code. Are you absolutely sure you don't have a bug and eg, concatenate strings to create a SQL query? Or trying to store DateTime values in a text field type?

Comment: On a web page, the *browser's* language settings control the display format, unless you hard-code it with page-level directives (don't). That's OK for intranet sites where you know the user's browser is set correctly. Public sites though allow users to specify the language as a preference that your application can read and use to set the response's language (and hence, date format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Aspnet Boilerplate Framework (v1.5.1), I don't need to modify the `web.config`. Just write the following code in the `global.asax.cs`:

```
protected virtual void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", true);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;
}
```

The problem was I wrote that code in `Application_BeginRequest` method. But I had to write that code in the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` method.

Comment: Change culture this way, can cause validation error on CreationTime property in Audit Entity. (It happened to me)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

//...
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  CultureInfo newCulture = (CultureInfo) System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MMM/yyyy";
  newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/";
  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```

you can use this or change the localization of your application in web.config as

```
<system.web>    
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to copy code without understanding what it actually does. The first snippet is pointless  since you can ask for the `en-GB` CultureInfo object with `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")` and avoid generating one temporary CultureInfo object per request. The *second* is the same configuration as the OP's. It's `culture` that control's formatting. `uiCulture` controls localized resources like messages and images.

Comment: BTW, the OP's code already uses the `en-GB` cultureinfo object.

Comment: I was having the same issue. then I added globalization in my web.config and it solved my problem. I just pasted my solution that worked for me.

Comment: that's still no different than what the OP did. You use the exact same `culture` setting as the OP. What you assume "worked" for you may be that you had *no* globalization settings. It doesn't mean that's a viable solution either - what about *users* that *don't* want this specific format?

Comment: ASP.NET Globalization is very well documented. There's no reason to hard-code anything. Check [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) which explains what each setting does and how to *properly* set them